# `Uncaught ReferenceError: floor is not defined` ao tentar usar floor e random para escolher um item de um array aleatoriamente

Tags: javascript, ionic2, typescript

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
var cartasViradas=[
    'assets/img/1.png',
    'assets/img/2.png',
    'assets/img/3.png',
    'assets/img/4.png',
    'assets/img/5.png',
    'assets/img/6.png',
    'assets/img/7.png',
    'assets/img/8.png',
    'assets/img/9.png',
    'assets/img/10.png'
];
```

E gostaria de saber como faço para conseguir de forma aleatória ter um desses valores do array dentro de uma variável.

Quando tento utilizar o método de `floor` e `random` num arquivo de extensão .ts do Ionic 2, recebo o seguinte erro:

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: floor is not defined`

Esse é o código que está causando o erro:

```
var selecionado = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Escolha aleatoriamente um da matriz cartasViradas
    var randomInd = floor(random(cartasViradas.length));
    var face = cartasViradas[randomInd];
    selecionado.push(face);
    selecionado.push(face);
    cartasViradas.splice(randomInd, 1);
}
```

Comment: Qual é a relação entre um arquivo TypeScript e não poder usar `floor` e `random`? A princípio, não teria problema. O que acontece quando você tenta?

Comment: As únicas soluções que já usei foi usando a biblioteca `Math`.. mas não quer dizer que seja impossível sem ela, mas porque não podes usa-la ?

Comment: Pablo ele mostra o seguinte erro quando tento "Uncaught ReferenceError: floor is not defined". É porque estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android com o ionic 2 e quando tento utilizar certos comandos do javascript em um arquivo TypeScript ele simplesmente não aceita e mostra esse erro que não está definido.

Comment: Coloque o código que está te dando esse erro. A chance é alta de ele ter alguma coisa errada.

Comment: var selecionado = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Escolha aleatoriamente um da matriz de faces
    var randomInd = floor(random(cartasViradas.length));
 var face = cartasViradas[randomInd];
 
    selecionado.push(face);
 selecionado.push(face);
 
    cartasViradas.splice(randomInd, 1);
} Esse dai é de acordo com esse array da minha pergunta

Comment: Seu problema é outro então.Vou editar sua pergunta com os novos detalhes, mas por favor, note que você teria conseguido uma ajuda muito mais fácil se tivesse ido direto à raiz do problema. Do jeito que está, você fez uma pergunta para um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)

Comment: Desculpa, mas pelo que eu entendi o TypeScript não aceita essa biblioteca por isso eu tinha pedido um método sem o floor e o random, mas vamos ver se sai alguma coisa ai e obrigado.

Comment: já tentou `Math.floor(x)`?

Comment: O que é esse `floor`? Não podes usar `Math.floor`?

Comment: Sim coloquei o Math. agora está dizendo que o random não está definido

Comment: Precisa do Math nos dois. Além disso, você está usando o random errado. Veja a minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`floor` e `random` são métodos do objeto `Math`. Você precisa fazer `Math.floor` e `Math.random`. Além disso, você estava passando o `length` como parâmetro para o `random`. O certo é multiplicar. Portanto, troque isso:

```
var randomInd = floor(random(cartasViradas.length));
```

Por isso:

```
var randomInd = Math.floor(Math.random()*cartasViradas.length);
```

Comment: Funcionou, só não entendi o porquê, é que estou seguindo os passos deste tutorial https://pt.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/memory-game/a/grid-of-tiles e da forma que está lá não funciona. buguei.

Comment: Também não entendi por que está desse jeito lá.

Comment: Provavelmente o autor da postagem no tal link criou funções próprias pra "simplificar" o uso do `Math.*` e esqueceu de adicionar aos exemplos.